# LocalDateTime field: MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, localdatetime

I have a main class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class ContentModel implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("serviceData")
     private ServiceData serviceData;
}
```

And nested-class:

```
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @Data
 @Builder
 public class ServiceData implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty ("dateTimeMessageSend")
    private LocalDateTime dateTimeMessageSend;
 }
```

I'm trying to deserialize this by using custom deserialiser:

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   protected LocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

   @Override
   public LocalDateTime deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt)
         throws IOException {
       return LocalDateTime.parse(jp.readValueAs(String.class));
    }
 }
```

This is, how I configure my objectMapper:

```
  JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());
    this.objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    this.objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    this.objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    this.objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

Application receive outside the following json:

```
{
 "serviceData": {
    "dateTimeMessageSend": {
       "month": "APRIL",
       "dayOfYear": 109,
       "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
       "nano": 183251000,
       "year": 2021,
       "monthValue": 4,
       "dayOfMonth": 19,
       "hour": 14,
       "minute": 52,
       "second": 44,
       "chronology": {
          "calendarType": "iso8601",
          "id": "ISO"
         }
      },
    }
 }
```

At the time of LocalDateTime-deserialization, I receive exception:

```
 MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

I suppose, that jackson recognise "dateTimeMessageSend" as an object and unable parse it as a string.

What the way to solve the problem?

1. Modify source json, for example by change LocalDateFormat to String. (What is undesirable)
2. Futher customization of objectMapper or/and LocalDateTimeDeserializer

Comment: If you're receiving *that* JSON, then the sender didn't have the `JavaTimeModule` registered. Highly recommended that the sender gets fixed. If you can't get the sender fixed, you need a *custom* deserializer that uses the [`LocalDateTime.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-) method to instantiate a `LocalDateTime` from that JSON Object data.

Comment: Andreas, something is becoming clear. But what you mean by "sender gets fixed"?

Comment: The sender of that JSON shouldn't build it like that. It should be `"dateTimeMessageSend": "2021-04-19T14:52:44.183251"`. The sending code needs to get fixed to do that, *if at all possible*. Then parsing at your end, the receiving end, will work correctly, without need for a custom deserializer.

Comment: Yes,  Andreas. I register in sender object mapper JavaTimeModule. And problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some misunderstanding about what you actually receive
in the `deserialize` method when Jackson calls your `LocalDateTimeSerializer`.

You do not just get a single long string like
`{ "month": "APRIL", "dayOfYear": 109, ... }`.
Therefore you cannot just simply call

```
jp.readValueAs(String.class);
```

You got a `MismatchedInputExcpetion` here, because the parser
encountered a `{` instead of a string `"something"`.

Actually you get a stream of tokens (beginning with `{`)
which you are supposed to consume up to the closing `}` token,
extract the relevant parts from this,
and build a `LocalDateTime` object from these parts.

See for example [Baeldung - Getting started with deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization),
especially the custom deserializer example given there.
Following this tuturial you can implement the `deserialize` method like this:

```
@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt)
         throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    int year = ((NumericNode) node.get("year")).asInt();
    int monthValue = ((NumericNode) node.get("monthValue")).asInt();
    int dayOfMonth = ((NumericNode) node.get("dayOfMonth")).asInt();
    int hour = ((NumericNode) node.get("hour")).asInt();
    int minute = ((NumericNode) node.get("minute")).asInt();
    int second = ((NumericNode) node.get("second")).asInt();
    return LocalDateTime.of(year, monthValue, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second);
}
```

Note that there is quite a bit of redundancy in the received JSON tree representing
the `LoclDateTime`. For example: it contains `"month": "APRIL"` *and*
`"monthValue": 4`. Therefore you don't need to extract all the
values from the tree, but only some them.

Comment: You're right. This is a solution. But I found more simple way.  I register in sender object mapper JavaTimeModule. And problem is solved

Comment: @Andrew Yes, using something like `"dateTimeMessageSend": "2021-04-19T14:52:44"` both on sender and receiver side is much simpler.